# Why is clang parsing this as a user-defined literal?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, clang++

I have some code I am maintaining that I've started compiling under clang 3.3.
When compiling with "-std=c++11", clang generates an error (given below). I've distilled the offending code to the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DBG_PRT(__format, ...) \
         printf("%s:%d:%s: "__format, __FILE__, \
                       __LINE__, __FUNCTION__, ## __VA_ARGS__)

int main()
{
    DBG_PRT("%s\n", "Hi");
}
```

This is clang's output:

> test.cpp:10:5: error: no matching literal operator for call to
>   'operator "" __format' with arguments of types 'const char *' and
>   'unsigned int'
>
> ```
> DBG_PRT("%s\n", "Hi");
>
> ^ test.cpp:4:29: note: expanded from macro 'DBG_PRT'
>      printf("%s:%d:%s: "__format, __FILE__, \
>                         ^ 1 error generated.
> ```

Without spaces between the string literal and "__format", it doesn't seem like the preprocessor should be able to expand __format. It clearly *is*, though, when not specifying -std=c++11. G++ 4.4.7 (with and without -std=c++0x) compiles just fine.

Is there an error with the compiler?

Comment: "__format" is a reserved identifier (double underscore). Try a different name.

Comment: Because `""_` is a syntax for user-defined string literals. Put a space in between to have the old behavior (concatenate literals). GCC works fine because 4.4.7 does not implement user defined literals (it appeared in 4.8 if my memory serves me).

Comment: @VladLazarenko: I think you should turn your comment to an answer + Fred's hint.

Comment: #fred: I didn't think of that. removed one "_" and clang quits complaining.

Comment: @Vlad: I'd already noticed a space gets clang to quit complaining. That is actually what got me thinking: why does the preprocessor expand "__format" if it isn't "standing alone"?

Comment: @John: This is because this feature affects preprocessor tokenization logic (the change covered in n2765 proposal). In other words, preprocessor does not expand those anymore (you can try `-E` option to check preprocessor output)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is because ""_ is a syntax for user-defined string literals. Put a space in between to have the old behavior (concatenate literals). GCC works fine because 4.4.7 does not implement user defined literals ([it appeared in version 4.7](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html)).

Also, as @Fred have pointed out, try to avoid using reserved identifier (double underscore).

Comment: Your memory's a liar, it was 4.7.